# Can we use python ThreadingHTTPServer in gunicorn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, gunicorn

I have an existing application which is written in python3 default threading based http server. Is it possible to use gunicorn on top of that?

I know in flaks application, we creare a wsgi file or an instance of application to gunicorn command.
Is there any similar way?

Comment: That depends on how your application is written and what has to be done to equip it with a WSGI interface. In general the WSGI interface replaces the webserver. Its job is done by gunicorn then.

Comment: `flask` has built-in HTTP server for tests but when you run `flask` with `gunicorn` then flask doesn't use this built-in HTTP server but `gunicorn` runs directly `flask` code - so `gunicorn` works instead of built-in HTTP server. Usually `gunicorn` is used also with `apache` or `nginx` which work as front-end HTTP server and probably you could use your `ThreadingHTTPServer` directly with `apache` or `nginx`.